# Installing adapta gtk theme

Tags: gnome, themes

I want to install adapta gtk theme on Ubuntu GNOME, but I can't find it in synaptic any more, and in terminal after adding the PPA it says `unable to locate package`

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Type **Software & Updates** in Dash and try to locate the service. From there, use **Other Software** tab. There is a list of PPAs already available. Just to be on the safer side remove the old Adapta PPA (if it exists) from it and try the following commands one by one

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tista/adapta
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adapta-gtk-theme
```

You can try referring to [this omgubuntu article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/10/install-adapta-gtk-theme-on-ubuntu) for further details

See also:

- [Launchpad Adapta PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tista/+archive/ubuntu/adapta)
- [Adapta project on GitHub](https://github.com/adapta-project/adapta-gtk-theme)

**Update** :

If the PPA method does not work, you can download from Github and use this method

Make sure that you unzip contents from Github to **.themes** folder in Home folder. If there is no **.themes** folder, create one.

To build and install system-wide, use these commands in terminal one by one after entering the .themes directory

```
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

[image]

Comment: Same problem unable to locate the package?

Comment: Can you see the PPA under " Other Software " ?

Comment: Yes I can see it

Comment: Is the same as the one given above ?

Comment: Updated answer with an alternative method.

Comment: Hi I did as you said and the autogen worked just fine but after I typed make I got this message (no targets specified and no makefile found)

Comment: @MuhammadHosny Try this https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1190851/  .Use the installation instructions described in it. Installation: unpack tarball into ~/.themes/ to install for current user only, or into /usr/share/themes/ or install .deb to install system-wide.

Comment: Thanks a lot that actually works and had a lot of colors too thanks a lot for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. Accept the answer by clicking the tick mark. :)